# stopwatch c# behave differently in different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, stopwatch

I'm currently using a stopwatch as a global timer. I have main thread running, another thread, and an event method.
The main thread launches the other thread and the event method is triggered by events. Both methods will call the stopwatch and get its time. The thing is, the times are not consistent:
from main thread:
START REC AT 9282
STOp REC AT 19290

from another thread:
audio 1
audio 304
audio 354
audio 404
audio 444
audio 494
audio 544
audio 594

from event method:
video 4
video 5
video 29
video 61
video 97
video 129
video 161

I don't get why if i start my rec at 9282, the other two functions that call the stopwatch will have timers that start at zero? Is this a thread related issue? How can i fix this? Thanks

UPDATE:*******************

when i save my frames i changed to:
long a = relogio.EllapseMilliseconds
i print out this value and its ok, as expected. but when i print the value stored in the lists, they come as starting from the beggining. strange huh?
SORRY FOR ALL THE TROUBLE, I PRINTED IT WITHOUT THE STARTING TIME,THATS WHY THEY ALL SEEMED TO START FROM ZERO! MANY THANKS AND SORRY!

main thread

```
   private void Start_Recording_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        rec_starting_time = relogio.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("START REC AT " + rec_starting_time);
        write_stream.enableRecording();

        Thread a = new Thread(scheduleAudioVideoFramePicks);
        a.Start();
```

scheduleAudioVideoFramePicks -  this thread just counts the time, so i know when to stop

```
       //while....
      if (rec_starting_time + time_Actual > rec_starting_time+recording_time * 1000)//1000 - 1s = 1000ms
            {
                totalRecordingTimeElapsed = true;
                write_stream.disableRecording();
                Console.WriteLine("STOp REC AT " + relogio.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
     //end while
    lock (list_audio)
        {
        int b = 0;
        //print time of frames gathered
        foreach(AudioFrame item in list_audio){
            Console.WriteLine("audio " + (item.getTime() - rec_starting_time));
        }
        lock (list_video)
        {
        }
        foreach (VideoFrame item in list_video)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("video " + (item.getTime() - rec_starting_time));
        }
        }
```

the another thread, where i get the time

```
     if (write_stream.isRecording())
            {

                list_audio.Enqueue(new AudioFrame(relogio.ElapsedMilliseconds, audioBuffer));

            }
```

event method

```
             if (write_stream.isRecording())
                    {

                        list_video.Add(new VideoFrame(relogio.ElapsedMilliseconds, this.colorPixels));


                    }~
```

i dont know if this is relevant, but i start my stopwatch like this

```
  public MainWindow()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //some code

        this.relogio = new Stopwatch();
        relogio.Start();

    }
```

Comment: Firstly, `Stopwatch` isn't thread-safe. Secondly, it's not possible to diagnose your issue without seeing the code.

Comment: Given a choice between a bug in Stopwatch or in the code that uses it, it is exceedingly simple to blame the code.  I know that Stopwatch works, I can't see your code.

Comment: edited to include code

Comment: its the same class, i only start the stopwatch one time, on mainWindow. The events only start when Start_Recording_Click is called (from a button). then write_stream.enableRecording(); enables the recording, and all the classes start to grab the audio and video frames. so thats why i dont get those times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stopwatch is not threadsafe, particularly for 32-bit programs.

It uses the Windows API call [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to update a private long field. On 32-bit systems you could get a "torn read" when one thread reads the long value while another thread is updating it.

To fix that, you'd have to put a lock around access to the Stopwatch.

Also note that one some older systems there were bugs where inconsistent values could be returned from different threads calling `QueryPerformanceCounter()`. From the documentation:

> On a multiprocessor computer, it should not matter which processor is called. However, you can get different results on different processors due to bugs in the basic input/output system (BIOS) or the hardware abstraction layer (HAL). To specify processor affinity for a thread, use the SetThreadAffinityMask function.

I have never encountered this bug myself, and I don't think it's very common.

What results do you get with the following test program? The times should be mostly increasing in value, but you are liable to get one or two out of order just because their threads get rescheduled just after they've read a value and before they add it to the queue.

```
namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        object locker = new object();
        ConcurrentQueue<long> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<long>();
        Barrier barrier = new Barrier(9);

        void run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                Task.Run(()=>test());

            barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Make sure all threads start "simultaneously"
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // Plenty of time for all the threads to finish.

            Console.WriteLine("Stopped");

            foreach (var elapsed in queue)
                Console.WriteLine(elapsed);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void test()
        {
            barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Make sure all threads start "simultaneously".

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                queue.Enqueue(elapsed());
        }

        long elapsed()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return sw.ElapsedTicks;
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Having said all that, the most obvious answer is that in fact you aren't sharing a single Stopwatch between the threads, but instead you have accidentally started a new one for each thread...

Comment: i get values and they increase line by line

Comment: @virgula24 That would seem to indicate that `Stopwatch` is working correctly on your system, which means the problem probably lies in your code somewhere. You should try using a locked access method to get the elapsed times like in my `long elapsed()` method above.

Comment: i edited my question to include the code. can u give a look at it?

Comment: @virgula24 I had a look, but I can't really see anything wrong other than you aren't locking access to `ElapsedMilliseconds` - you need to fix that. I also can't see the where you are printing the audio and video timestamps.

Comment: i made the locks but still the same. edited code to add the prints

Comment: Well the prints look wrong: `Console.WriteLine("video " + (item.getTime() - rec_starting_time))` doesn't seem to be using just the number passed in from `ElapsedMilliseconds`

Comment: i got where the error was, on the prints.. many thanks for the help!!